# How to add column into the database?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, sql

In my module I need add one column to the eav_attribute_option so created a simple script:

```
  /* @var $this Mage_Core_Mode_Resource_Setup */
    $this->startSetup();
    $this->run("
    CREATE TABLE eav_attribute_option (
        `show_brand` BOOLEAN,
        );
        ");
    $this->endSetup();
```

**Instantly getting error:**

```
a:5:{i:0;s:332:"Error in file: "/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local/Amber/Checkbox/sql/checkbox_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.0.0.0.1-0.0.0.0.2.php" - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 3";i:1;s:954:"#0 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
```

**I'm sorry guys, silly me , ALTER TABLE .**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  /* @var $this Mage_Core_Mode_Resource_Setup */
    $this->startSetup();
    $this->run("
        ALTER TABLE eav_attribute_option add column `show_brand` BOOLEAN;   
    ");
    $this->endSetup();
```